# How to draw a line with a custom round pen in Qt

Tags: qt, qpainter

I have Tile and code for generate polyline:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
        QWidget *widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);

        QBrush brush;
        brush.setTexture(QPixmap(":/light.png").scaledToWidth(8, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
        brush.setStyle(Qt::TexturePattern);

        QPen pen(brush, 8, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin);

        QPainter painter(widget);
        painter.setPen(pen);

        /* path */
        qreal startX = 10.0;
        qreal startY = widget->height()/2;

        QVector<QPointF> v = {
            QPointF(startX + 0 ,    startY + 0),
            QPointF(startX + 25,    startY + 20),
            QPointF(startX + 50,    startY + 30),
            QPointF(startX + 75,    startY - 10),
            QPointF(startX + 100,   startY + 10),
            QPointF(startX + 125,   startY - 20),
            QPointF(startX + 150,   startY - 5),
            QPointF(startX + 175,   startY + 15),
            QPointF(startX + 200,   startY + 0)
        };
        QPolygonF polygon(v);

        painter.drawPolyline(polygon);
    }

    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

After executing I get this image:

[image: Bad polyline]

but need to get a polyline like this:

[image: True polyline]

How to implement it?

Comment: What you need to do is not just textured line, you need to rotate your light.png according to the line angle, this will led to image quality degradation and will be slow. If you just need blurred line I'd suggest to paint simple polyline and than apply something like Gaussian Blur

Comment: This isn't a Gaussian blur. You'll need to paint a thin line on a `QImage`, then use an image processing library to apply a suitable kernel. Or you'll need to use a `QOpenGLWidget`, let the `QPainter` do the initial painting, and set a suitable blur fragment shader.

Comment: I think that the use of blur will be also very slow, unlike to the use of ready-made textures. 
Image rotation does not help, because the QPainter begin drawing a pen background with zero points of widget (at [0;0] point). 
Look at my screenshot in a left edge: the tile on a line is not drawn at the start point.

In reality, I need a lightning effect like as "Lightning Bolt" or "Arc Lightning" in Warcraft III game. 
I noticed that in a game uses the prepared image which distorted in a randomly directions:
Screenshot: [Warcraft III Lightning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iJvYR.png)